# Preprocessing Time Windows Width in Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, vehicle-routing, supply-chain, logistics

I think my model takes much time because the time windows width given the problem i want to solve.
Here is the time matrix:

```
0   23  73  71  61  58  35  22  57  57  56  55  55  53  53  52  48
23  0   5   6   24  19  19  17  23  17  18  20  34  22  22  21  22
15  5   0   4   28  23  23  23  22  21  23  24  24  27  27  26  26
23  6   4   0   29  23  23  22  22  21  23  24  23  26  26  25  24
61  24  28  29  0   7   8   9   10  12  11  10  10  10  10  12  20
58  19  23  23  7   0   1   3   3   5   4   4   4   5   6   7   14
58  19  23  23  8   1   0   2   2   4   4   3   3   5   5   6   13
12  17  11  22  9   3   2   0   1   3   3   4   3   6   6   6   13
57  18  22  22  5   3   2   1   0   3   2   3   3   5   5   6   12
57  17  21  21  12  5   4   3   3   0   2   4   3   6   6   5   10
56  18  23  22  11  4   4   3   2   2   0   2   2   4   5   4   10
55  20  24  24  10  4   3   4   3   4   2   0   1   3   3   3   11
23  19  24  23  10  4   3   3   3   3   2   1   0   3   3   4   11
53  22  23  26  10  5   5   6   5   6   4   3   3   0   1   2   11
53  23  27  26  10  6   5   6   5   6   5   3   3   1   0   2   11
52  21  26  25  12  7   6   6   6   5   4   3   4   2   2   0   9
48  22  26  45  20  34  13  13  12  10  10  11  11  11  11  9   0
```

The case is i want a route for perishable product that deliver the product under like 8 hours, given the 17x17 time matrix above. There are nodes that are really close to each others.
So the earliest will be all 0 for all nodes. And the latest will be all 480 (in minutes) for all nodes too. The service time is about 13 minutes for each nodes. Does anyone have any advice regarding this problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but I don't see your time windows or their width?

Comment: What kind of advice are you asking for? Regarding time-windows just use 480-13 as the time-window ends in case service needs to be done before the 8 hours.